# Group similar spelled character strings together and assign id's in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, grouping, data-wrangling

I have a table of 10,000 unique names. Using the `package(fuzzyjoin)` I would like to match these unique names to names that are only spelled with 1 different letter. I would like to group the different spelling matches so that they can be assessed for misspelling and corrected in the dataset.

An example using baby names is below. I try to match the original name column to a new column, `name_match`, based on a single letter difference `(max_dist = 1)`.

So for example, Aadam and Adam are matched because they only differ by a single letter, the extra 'a'. I want to group these two together in the dataset so that a unique ID refers to both names since they are the same, but one is misspelled.

```
baby_data <- 
  data.frame(babynames) %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  filter(str_starts(name, 'A'))

name_match <- 
  baby_data %>% 
  stringdist_left_join(.,
                       baby_data %>% 
                         rename(name_match = name),
                       max_dist = 1,
                       by = c('name' = 'name_match')) %>% 
  # remove rows where the names are the same
  filter(!(name == name_match))
```

A few complications arise; first, Aadam and Adam both show up as matches for each other in both columns (i.e., Aadam = Adam, Adam = Aadam). I only need one record to show the match.

Second, how do I group them? Ideally, the final table would look something like:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Aadam |
| 1 | Adam |
| 2 | Anne |
| 2 | Ann |

I feel like there is a `case_when()` or `if_else() problem nested into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we remove all duplicates from `name_match` in the sense that e.g. `(Adam, Aadam) = (Aadam, Adam)`. To the remaining entries we assign an `id` to each tuple and finally unpivot the data.

```
name_match |>

    # remove all "duplicates"
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(key = paste(sort(c(name, name_match)), collapse = "")) |>
    distinct(key, .keep_all = T) |>
    select(-key) |>
    ungroup() |>

    # assign an id to each tuple of names
    mutate(id = row_number()) |>
    pivot_longer(name:name_match) |>
    select(-name) |>
    rename(name = value)
```

Note that every name can appear multiple times in the result. Here is one example:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     id name 
  <int> <chr>
1  1958 Adam 
2  1958 Adham
3  1965 Adam 
4  1965 Aadam
```